# Seg faulting on a car cast from unsigned char to const char in C++

Tags: c++

Code:

```
const char* copyoutmsg(unsigned char instring[2055])    
{    
    char* msg = "";    
    const char* wholestring = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(instring);    
    strncpy(msg,wholestring,eotpos-5);    
    printf("Message: %s\n",msg);    
    return msg;    
}
```

It's seg faulting (process returning 139) - can't get my head round it. Eotpos is the position of the end of the message. What this function is meant to do is input an unsigned char array, convert it to const char and return the message minus 5 chars from the end. I cannot see what is causing this.

Comment: It's your own fault for not paying attention to compiler warnings, or even not enabling compiler warnings...

Comment: In addition, this question doesn't have anything about C++

Comment: @Manu Not true, there is no `reinterpret_cast` in C. Hence, this question is correctly tagged.

Comment: @Manu343726 What you're eluding to is the increasingly rampant site-wide opinion that unless you're coding with the C++ standard library (a *superset* of the C standard library), you're not coding in C++, and that just isn't true. I concur anyone that wants to use C++ and *doesn't* exploit the joyous world its library coupled with RAII offers is doing themselves a disservice, but its their funeral.

Comment: @Manu343726: The crucial part of the question, namely the type of a string literal, is different in C and C++, so the tagging matters.

Comment: @WhozCraig (and Kerrek) I will keep that in mind in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all other problems in your code, segfault source is in these statements:

```
char* msg = "";    
const char* wholestring = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(instring);    
strncpy(msg,wholestring,eotpos-5);
```

You're trying to copy the string pointed by `wholestring` into a memory location where `msg` is pointing to. `msg` is pointing in the read-only part of the memory, where the string literals are stored (see the first statement of your code). You need to allocate memory for the message first:

```
char* msg = new char[eotpos - 5 + 1];    
const char* wholestring = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(instring);    
strncpy(msg,wholestring,eotpos-5);
```

Don't forget to delete memory afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you **cannot** initialize a `char*` from a string literal in C++11. The clause which allowed that initialization in C++98 and C++03 was removed. If you worked out why that is, you have a hint on one thing which went wrong! You may want to read up on memory allocation as well or, better yet, use proper C++ facilities like `std::string` as raw pointer manipulators are fairly hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but you don't allocate any memory for `msg`, of course it will segfault if you try to copy a string to it.

Besides, if `eotpos` is the *position* of the last message character (and it does not point to the string termination literal), the message has the length of `eotpos+1` (without the string termination literal), since the counting starts with 0. That is why you will have to allocate `eotpos+1-5+1` characters for `msg` (the last `+1` is being used for the string termination literal).

Initialize `msg` like this:

```
char* msg = malloc(eotpos-3); // Or new char[eotpos - 3], when I answered, there was still just the C tag
msg[eotpos-4] = 0;
```

And then copy:

```
strncpy(msg,wholestring,eotpos-4);
```

Well, depending on what `eotpos` really is, you have to fix the constant values above. But in my opinion, your description is a little value.